# How do you remove one box to continue a 'for' loop in java?

Tags: java, graphics, acm-java-libraries

I'm new to java and I am trying to write a code that generates 10 random boxes then removes one box and adds another. Thus the total remains 10 boxes, but the loop keeps going. I have figured out how to create the 10 random boxes, but I am unsure how to remove one from that. here is the code:

```
final int width = 800;
        final int height = 600;
        final int boxWidth = 50;
        final int maxBoxes = 10;

        this.setSize(width, height);
            Random random = new Random();

                for(int box=0;box<maxBoxes;box++)
                {
                    int x = random.nextInt(width-boxWidth);
                    int y = random.nextInt(height-boxWidth);
                    GRect r = new GRect(x, y, boxWidth, boxWidth);
                    Color c = new Color(random.nextInt(256),
                                        random.nextInt(256), random.nextInt(256));
                    r.setFilled(true);
                    r.setFillColor(c);
                    this.add(r);

                    this.pause(100);
```

Comment: What is the type of the class this code is from?

Comment: _how to remove one from that_ based on what condition you want to remove a box?

Comment: i think one will be removed at random and replaced with another box at a random position.

Comment: give the code for _this.add(r);_ method. we will know what data structure you are using so that we can give you a plausible solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the box values in an array.  Then in each iteration of your loop erase the screen and redraw all 10 boxes.  Then randomly replace the box values for one box and repeat.